# postgres: crosstab and remove duplicates on query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have data which needs to have its values converted to columns **during** a query:

```
SELECT p.*,
CASE WHEN s.stat_id=1 THEN s.base_stat END AS "hp",
CASE WHEN s.stat_id=2 THEN s.base_stat END AS "attack",
CASE WHEN s.stat_id=3 THEN s.base_stat END AS "defense",
CASE WHEN s.stat_id=4 THEN s.base_stat END AS "special_attack",
CASE WHEN s.stat_id=5 THEN s.base_stat END AS "special_defense",
CASE WHEN s.stat_id=6 THEN s.base_stat END AS "speed"
FROM pokemon_stats s
INNER JOIN pokemon p on s.pokemon_id=p.id
```

Which gives:

[image: duplicate values]

In the table `pokemon_stats`, a new row exists individually for each stat.

[image: duplicate stats]

How can I write my query, using crosstab or without it, so that the duplicates are removed?

Comment: Is it postgres of MySQL ?

Comment: Use sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=1 THEN s.base_stat END) as "hp" and similarly for other columns.

Comment: Hi. Use text for text--[don't use images/links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Read & act on [mcve]. And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `crosstab` function:

First, install the [tablefunc module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tablefunc.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

SELECT *
FROM pokemon p
JOIN crosstab('SELECT 
                   pokemon_id
                 , stat_id
                 , base_stat
               FROM pokemon_stats
               WHERE stat_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
               ORDER BY 1, 2') xtab (id integer
                                   , hp integer
                                   , attack integer
                                   , defense integer
                                   , special_attack integer
                                   , special_defense integer
                                   , speed integer) 
     USING (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT p.id, p.identifier, p.species_id, p.height, p.weight, p.base_experience, p.order ,p.is_default,
sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=1 THEN s.base_stat END) AS "hp",
sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=2 THEN s.base_stat END) AS "attack",
sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=3 THEN s.base_stat END) AS "defense",
sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=4 THEN s.base_stat END) AS "special_attack",
sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=5 THEN s.base_stat END) AS "special_defense",
sum(CASE WHEN s.stat_id=6 THEN s.base_stat END) AS "speed"
FROM pokemon_stats s
INNER JOIN pokemon p on s.pokemon_id=p.id
group by 
p.id, p.identifier, p.species_id, p.height, p.weight, p.base_experience, p.order ,p.is_default
```